# Sending POST on /login spring security with postman

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm struggling with log into my application with postman. I'm using spring security with simple configuration:

```
package main.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/createUser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createUser")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

I'm sending POST request on `/login`so that I could log in, but all the time I get:

[photo from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t27PZ.png)

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How am I supposed to log in and oparte on postman normally? What is interesting if I try to get page within my browser, I'm asked for credentials and then I'm succesfully logged in.

I want to access my other pages which are protected and test them using POSTMAN.

Comment: You are getting 200 OK which means Spring Security is able to match your details and configured HTML content is returned. What is redirection URL when user details are matched ? What is your expectation ?

Comment: if I put bad password I get HTTP 200 also. My expectation is to use postman normally, so that I dont get 'Please sign in' for every request

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer, lack of `httpBasic()`

Conf class:

```
package main.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint;


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity()
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public WebSecurityConfiguration(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/createUser").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll().and().httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createUser");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In that case can you please change below as of now and take it from there ?

```
@Override
protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
      .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass")).roles("POSTMAN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/success.html", true) // example page where request need to be redirected when login is sucessful.
      .and()
      .logout()
      .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
}
```

Try above username and password using in memory implementation first and then configure databaseservice later.
Create success.html and you should see the same after login attempt

If you want to test internal URL's through POSTMAN without authentication/ authorization then comment .anyRequest().authenticated() during testing.

Comment: I'm not sure. Why do I need to have some `.html` pages?

Comment: Tbh, I didn't add this page, but pasted your configuration and still getting 'Please sign in'

Comment: What is interesting if I try to get page within my browser, I'm asked for credentials and then I'm succesfully logged in.

Comment: It could be because POSTMAN cannot handle redirects but internally browser is doing server side redirects. Why you want to utilise Postman for this ?

Comment: To have a possibility to use POST method as within browser I cannot

Comment: When you submit your login details on browser which is essentially POST method. I don't think you have any problem.

Comment: I want to send other POST method rather than log in.... like adding data, but I dont have front for that

Comment: You have to disable spring security layer when you are trying to POSTMAN. You have to modify the question to reflect what you want to achieve.

Comment: Tbh. you don't adress my question at all... I don't want to create any user via conifugration, don't want to create default success page, just want to log in and that's all...

Comment: I think you are not making your question clear. Let me know below is your expectation ?  1. You have a login page 2. You have some user configuration to allow users to login using your existing code. 3. You have some pages which you haven't really developed as of now. 4. You have some API's which you want to test without frontend, as of because you don't have fronend ready . Can you please confirm all above or correct me if I understood wrong?